# What is the minimum amount of time you need to wait before calling out to an NTP server again? (wait at least 64/128/10000/etc. seconds)

Tags: hardware, ntp

What is the minimum amount of time you need to wait before requesting time again from an NTP server? I've seen a wide variety of answers, but I'm looking to get a good ballpark.

Is it OK to query an NTP server every 5 minutes? I've heard if you query too much they'll IP address ban you and I'm using the [NIST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Standards_and_Technology) NTP server so I'm worried about getting IP address banned from a US government server.

I'm looking to not have to deal with an [RTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock) in my hardware prototype.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the server; typically, NTP will start at 64 seconds and stabilize up to 1024 seconds.  Cisco uses [iburst](https://everythingwhat.com/what-is-iburst-in-ntp) by default, but they tend to stay up; otherwise iburst can cause issues/blocks.